# Using recorder in IBM Rational Performance Tester

Tags: performance, testing, automated-tests, performance-testing, rational-performance-test

I have a question in IBM RPT, when I’m doing HTTP test via browser there are 2 Recording Method ( Socket Recorder, Proxy Recorder).

As User Manual :

HTTP proxy recorder: Use when proxy connections are required to connect to the network

Socket recorder: Use for low-level network traffic when the client does not support proxies

When I’m using Proxy Recorder, the browser automatically generate a port ([Screen capture](http://i766.photobucket.com/albums/xx302/hongsonbk1991/ask_2_zpsaiaafgyc.png)) at my Localhost proxy (as you can see at here [Choosing Recorder type](http://i766.photobucket.com/albums/xx302/hongsonbk1991/recorder_zpsuvqshcer.png)). And the recording work normaly (it works faster than Socket Recorder, when i'm using Socket Recorder it works too slow and sometimes it does not receive any packets!). 
Which method should I choose for testing Web App?  Is each method affect the performance results?

Please help me fix those problem. I'm sorry cause the attachment i do not have enough point to add a picture

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

what version you are using ?? 
If you are using 8.1 go to LAN setting in your PC and disable the proxy Click Apply then save if later let me know